# Can't find the source of this "Expected Identifier" error, any thoughts?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm very new to Objective-C and programming in general and I'm having some difficulty solving a strange error I'm getting in my code. I've rechecked my code line-by-line but no matter what I do I get an "Expected Identifier" error on this one line.

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your total is $%.2f", [self.cartTotal]];
```

I've retyped the line several times to make sure that I wasn't missing any typos, but a little red arrow is pointing to the first closing bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take `[self.cartTotal]` out of the brackets.  They're unnecessary here.

Should be:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your total is $%.2f", self.cartTotal];
```

---

To help understand the error (assuming you're coming from a language like Java or C++), what you've written is the equivalent to writing this in say Java:

```
this.cartTotal.
```

Notice the hanging dot at the end?  That's what you've done here basically.  In Java, that dot suggests you're calling a method on whatever object `cartTotal` is, or access a public variable on that object.  I'm not sure what a Java or C++ error message would say here, but this is the equivalent scenario.

---

Given @GregParker's excellent comment...

You created `cartTotal` by way of a `@property`.

```
@property double cartTotal; // or something like this
```

This creates three things:

- A setter
- A getter
- An instance variable

The setter is accessed in two ways:

```
[self setCartTotal:value];
```

Or:

```
self.cartTotal = value;
```

These both do the same thing.

The getter is likewise accessed in two ways:

```
[self cartTotal];
```

Or:

```
self.cartTotal;
```

Comment: `self.cartTotal` or `[self cartTotal]`. Not both.

Comment: Thanks for that comment Greg.  I added some to the answer for Objective-C beginners.